# Android - Set Access permision to a partiion

Tags: embedded-linux, android-source

I am new to Embedded -linux. I have set the BoardConfig.mk file to create a root directory "test"(BOARD_ROOT_EXTRA_FOLDERS += test). How can I set read-write permission to that partition. Right now , I can't do a mkdir inside that folder as it throws an exception "Read only system"

Comment: what is filesystem type?

Comment: the filesystem type is ext4

Comment: Could you try to remount your folder(partition) as rw? By default the Android root file system come with read only.

Comment: you mean remount using adb commands?

Comment: using 'mount' command. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html